# Is it possible to jump by using only my arms?

Tags: momentum

We can see that basketball players use their arms to jump higher.

Is it possible to lose contact with the ground by only moving my arms?

I know that the calculations have something to do with momentum, but how massive and how fast should the arms be moved to achieve this effect?

EDIT:

The given answers consider moving only the arms in a downward motion to force the rest of the body to go the opposite direction.

I've found that there is another way which requires some kind of contact with the ground.

Let's say we have 2 heavy dumbbells. We then proceed to rapidly throw the up in the air, without letting go. I think that if we throw them hard enough, the body will be forced to go along.

If we remove the dumbbells I guess it might be possible as well, but would require bigger speed change.

Are the equations required to calculate this similar to moving the arms only downwards?

Comment: You can't jump without applying a normal force on the ground(wether pushing with your feet or arms) as the ground would only push you back with a force $-F$ you applied at first this is due to Newton third law. So jumping without applying a force on the ground is -as far as I know- not possible

Comment: I agree that there has to be a contact with the ground through the feet. But I was wondering more about not using the muscles in the legs.

Comment: Well, without hurting yourself, if you tried it with say bodybuilder's weights, and could not do it, then arms alone won't do it. Half the mass of your arms, at the very  least, does not go above your head when you circle your arms.

Comment: How could I calculate the mass needed to lose contact with the ground?

Comment: You need an upward force greater than your weight, obviously for a tiny time. I just can't see how you can avoid millions of years of evolution telling you to push up with your legs. Anyway, don't hurt yourself, and if you **can** do it, put it up on youtube:)

Comment: @OussamaBoussif - that is not true. You can lift off without applying force to the ground. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone invoked Icarus yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the *principle* and the *practice*.

Let's look at the principle. If you have two arms, each with mass $m$, and length $\ell$, we could restate your question as saying: "how, and how fast, do I have to move such arms to make my body lift off?". That's quite easy.

Assume you are holding your arms out sideways. Their center of mass is at $\ell/2$, and their total mass is $2m$. If you move your arms down rapidly, there will be a net vertical force on the rest of your body. Move the arms fast enough, and you will lift off:

[image]

Simple conservation of momentum says that if you move your hands down at velocity $v$, you are moving a mass of $2m$ down at velocity $v/2$ and so the net downward momentum is $mv$. In the absence of gravity, this would be compensated by the body moving up at velocity $V = \frac{m}{M}v$. However, gravity does play a role - which is why you have to move your arms *fast* if you want to get liftoff in this way.

To figure this out we have to remember that $F\Delta t = m\Delta v$ - the faster the change in momentum, the greater the force. In this case, we need to overcome the force on arms plus body: $F_g = (2m+M)g$. If we consider that you accelerate the arms from zero to $v$ in $\delta t$, then the velocity $v$ can be calculated from

$$(2m+M)g \delta t < m v\\
v > \frac{2m+M}{m} g \delta t$$

Putting in reasonable values for mass of arms 6 kg each, and rest of body 60 kg (lean athlete), you need $v/\delta t > 60 m/s^2$. It might not be humanly possible to get sufficient force from the shoulders to move the arms that quickly - although it's not hard to see that the force will be similar to the force needed to perform "the cross" - a very demanding gymnastics move ([here demonstrated by Yuri van Gelder](http://images.inmagine.com/400nwm/iris/imagebrokerrm-240/ptg01310277.jpg) doing the L cross - requiring incredible effort from shoulders and abdomen):

[image]

The reasoning that this is the same force that would provide the lift needed for the body - but where the move as shown above is done statically, you would have to do this dynamically - so there would be not just force, but force and speed.

So while it is theoretically possible, I doubt it could be done practically.

Of course moving the arms in various ways can certainly *help* - I am traying to answer the question "can you lift off with just your arms". I know I couldn't...

Comment: (+1) Very detailed and organized answer. Now I understand. And using the same principle we can justify why moving wings for birds helps them fly cant we?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif - thanks. For birds, the movement of the wings has far more complex aerodynamic reasons; I don't think that the inertial effect I describe would be important for them.

Comment: For the question given, the idea is that simply the mass of the arms can't be moved down fast enough to give sufficient momentum.  But with a wing, you get to (hopefully) add a large mass of air.  That makes it easier.

Comment: Great answer!  I've found that doing a bit more yields better results. This is done by moving the arms upwards first and then rapidly downwards. Looks like the change of acceleration is much bigger.

Comment: Floris and @BowlOfRed thanks for taking the time to explain, I appreciate it ;)

Comment: @Floris I have updated my question with a follow up. Could you take a look? :)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you can try to move your arms downwards (for a short time), that would tend to move the rest of your body upwards. The mass of the arms is approximately 10% of the total weight of the man's body (http://www.timesdaily.com/archives/weighing-in-on-individual-body-parts/article_4729f5a7-c039-5649-910e-ee18a03435e0.html ). To have the rest of your body to accelerate with acceleration g (to counteract gravity), your arms should move with (average) acceleration 9g. Is it possible with human anatomy (note that the shoulders are static) - I don't know.